# Can a well-enhanced Double Jump substitute for Triple Jump?

Tags: a-valley-without-wind-2

In *A Valley Without Wind 2*, there are Stratospheric Citadels that, supposedly, you can't complete unless you have Triple Jump. (The Evil Overlord's keep also can't be completed without it, though it can be entered and you can improved mage classes there.)

**In my current game, I have Double Jump, plus access to several perks that will enhance my jump height. Can I break the sequence, skip getting Triple Jump, and go for the end-game now, by clearing both of the Citadels and the Evil Overlord's Keep?** I've already located both Stratospheric Citadels, but I can't spot any other Research Facilities at the moment, so finding Triple Jump will be a bit tricky for me.

(I've tried entering one of the Citadels. There's a cliff at the beginning that claims to require Triple Jump, but I can clear it with a well-enhanced single jump. Unfortunately, I don't see anything that looks like a Citadel, stratospheric or not. Does the entrance not appear until I have Triple Jump, or am I just not spotting it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having now beaten the game, I can conclusively say: **Yes, an enhanced Double Jump can substitute for Triple Jump.** There's no magic game-logic that prevents you from finishing the game, there's just some high jumps to make.

It turns out that the Stratospheric Citadels aren't anything special; in my game, they were just ordinary Craggy Highlands tiles. They were a bit longer than normal, but it's the same as purifying any other tile: march to the end of the level, destroy the weather-manipulating thing, and then you're done. (And then Demonaica will cast spells over the Citadel tile to try to prevent you from clearing it with resistance members, but that's another story.)

The Evil Overlord's Keep is a similar story: there are places where you need to jump high, but an enhanced Double Jump can do the job.